# Binary Subtraction of Two Unsigned Integers

Tags: binary

For unsigned integers $ X = 00110101 $ and $ Y = 10110101 $, determine the following values:

$ X + Y = (\text{My answer is}) ~ 11101010 $.

$ X - Y = ~ ??? $

$ Y - X = ~ ??? $

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps try to define `01-10` and `10-01` in binary first, and then try to tackle your problem.

Comment: Another hint: $X-Y = -(Y-X)$.

Comment: Yes I understand that this would come out to -10000000. However, "unsigned" integers can't be negative...so how do I do this then

Comment: If your answer is supposed to be unsigned, $X-Y$ has no answer

Comment: @RossMillikan he is likely asking how this is actually done on a computer, say in C++ programming -- using 2's complement... See Amzoti's answer below.

Comment: Please stop defacing your questions.

Comment: Amzoti and I have spent some effort to answer your question.  Why did you delete it?

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is correct for $X+Y = 11101010$

Hint (Algorithm): $X-Y$

- Determine $Y’s$ $2’s$ complement $X+$ (2’s complement of $Y$)
- If $X \ge Y$, an end carry will result. Discard the end carry.
- If $X \lt Y$, no end carry will result.  To obtain the answer in a
  familiar form, take the 2’s complement of the sum and place a
  negative sign in front.

You may want to display in a different form, but you did not specify (hint: convert the first answer to 2's complement form).

$$X - Y = -10000000 ~~\text{and}~~ Y - X = 10000000$$

Comment: Good work, Amzoti! +1

Comment: @amWhy: I have to admit that this has never been a good way to have defined it in general. I suppose this makes it easy for logic circuits, but hard for humans! :-)

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly! But I enjoy doing "two's complement" arithmetic...I don't know why...I guess it's an exercise in logic, to some extent...

Answer (score 1):

For $Y-X$ you do it just like base $10$.  In this case there are no borrows.  For unsigned, there is no answer to $X-Y$ because negative numbers cannot be represented.

$$\ \ \ 10110101\\ \underline{-00110101}\\\ \ \ 10000000$$

Comment: @SilentMan:  yes, the high order bit is not taken as a sign, it is taken as a bit of the number.  So in $8$ bits you can represent the numbers $0$ through $2^8-1=255$, while with signed numbers you can represent $-128$ through $127$ in two's complement

Comment: "Unsigned" computer arithmetic usually means that the operations are done $\bmod 2^n$, where $n$ is the word size. It does  not mean that $X-Y$ is undefined when $X<Y$, but rather that the result is $X-Y+2^n$.

Comment: @SilentMan:  I would say you do two's complement to represent negative numbers.  It is one representation, sign/magnitude is another.

Comment: @SilentMan:$-128_{10}=10000000$ in two's complement as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)  If you have more bits, you put more $1$'s on the left.  You can't represent $+128_{10}$ in a single byte of two's complement.

Answer (score 1):

For X=00110101 and Y=10110101,

Binary Addition X + Y = 11101010

Binary Subtraction X - Y = -10000000

Binary Multiplication X * Y = 0010010101111001

Binary Division X / Y = 0000

Check results @ [Binary Arithmetic Calculator](https://www.easycalculation.com/binaryarith.php)

Answer (score 0):

Step: 1. Take 2's compliment of -ve number.

Step: 2. Add it to +ve number

Step: 3. If most significant bit is 0 then write answer with avoiding end carry

Step: 4. If most significant bit is 1 then take 2's compliment of answer again and place negative sign with answer

X-Y => 00110101
      -10110101
Take 2's compliment of 10110101
=>01001010
=>00111011

Then add it to first number
=>10000000

We know that MSB is 1. So the answer should be in negative. To make it negative take 2's compliment of answer again
=> 01111111
=> 10000000
X-Y =>-10000000

For Y-X
 Y => 10110101
 X =>-10110101
Take 2's compliment to X
=> 01001010
-X => 01001011

Add it to Y
110000000
There is an end carry so answer will be in positive automatically. Ignore and carry and write answer
10000000